# TemplateSyntaxError trying to use cut filter in template tag in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I am trying to set a link href as part of the current URL path in my Django view template. But I am currently getting the error

> Could not parse some characters:
>   request.get_full_path|()||cut:'?thumbnail=true'

This is my code

```
{% if 'thumbnail' in 'request.get_full_path()' %}
    <a href="{{ request.get_full_path()|cut:'?thumbnail=true' }}">Link</a>
{% endif %}
```

Why am I getting this error? Can I use the cut filter this way?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not call functions like you do in python code. Instead do this:

```
{{ request.get_full_path|cut:'?thumbnail=true' }}
```

Comment: Ah! Oh dear. Thank you! I'll accept your answer when it lets me :)